# Create matrix with line info from different files

Tags: r

I have 3 files (format given below).
File 3 has 3 columns -

1. column 1 contains the line number from the file 1
2. column 2 contains the line number from the file 2
3. column 3 unique info

I want to create another file which has information from all three files in the following format

```
AT1G01020   SAMN10267760-CAGATCAAGATGGCGT   41.409866
AT1G01040   SAMN10267760-CAGATCAAGATGGCGT   6.901644
AT1G01050   SAMN10267760-CAGATCAAGATGGCGT   848.9022
```

File 1

```
AT1G01010   AT1G01010
AT1G01020   AT1G01020
AT1G01030   AT1G01030
AT1G01040   AT1G01040
AT1G01050   AT1G01050
```

File 2

```
SAMN10267760-CAGATCAAGATGGCGT
SAMN10267760-TAAGCGTTCATCGATG
SAMN10267760-CGCCAAGCAAGCGTAG
SAMN10267760-CGTTCTGTCTGACCTC
SAMN10267760-GTCGTAAGTAGGGACT
SAMN10267760-CTCGAGGCAGCGTAAG
SAMN10267760-GTGCGGTCACTGCCAG
SAMN10267760-GACACGCGTTCTGAAC
SAMN10267760-TGGCTGGAGCCGATTT
SAMN10267760-CAGATCAGTTCGTCTC
```

File 3

```
2 1 41.409866
4 1 6.901644
5 1 848.9022
```

Hope I explain my problem clearly. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dput()` to include your data in the future:

```
File1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("AT1G01010", "AT1G01020", "AT1G01030", 
"AT1G01040", "AT1G01050"), V2 = c("AT1G01010", "AT1G01020", "AT1G01030", 
"AT1G01040", "AT1G01050")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
File2 <- structure(list(V1 = c("SAMN10267760-CAGATCAAGATGGCGT", "SAMN10267760-TAAGCGTTCATCGATG", 
"SAMN10267760-CGCCAAGCAAGCGTAG", "SAMN10267760-CGTTCTGTCTGACCTC", 
"SAMN10267760-GTCGTAAGTAGGGACT", "SAMN10267760-CTCGAGGCAGCGTAAG", 
"SAMN10267760-GTGCGGTCACTGCCAG", "SAMN10267760-GACACGCGTTCTGAAC", 
"SAMN10267760-TGGCTGGAGCCGATTT", "SAMN10267760-CAGATCAGTTCGTCTC"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
File3 <- structure(list(V1 = c(2L, 4L, 5L), V2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), V3 = c(41.409866, 
6.901644, 848.9022)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

File4 <- data.frame(Col1=File1[File3[, 1], 1], Col2=File2[File3[, 2], 1], Col3=File3[, 3])
File4
#        Col1                          Col2       Col3
# 1 AT1G01020 SAMN10267760-CAGATCAAGATGGCGT  41.409866
# 2 AT1G01040 SAMN10267760-CAGATCAAGATGGCGT   6.901644
# 3 AT1G01050 SAMN10267760-CAGATCAAGATGGCGT 848.902200
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly